# Partial generic interface with type constraint

Tags: c#, generics, interface, type-constraints

I need to create two partial interfaces. One with a constraint and the other without, like:

```
public partial interface IMyCuteInterface<T> where T : IEnumerable
{
    void DoSomethingOnlyPossibleIfGenericIsIEnumerable();
}

public partial interface IMyCuteInterface<T>
{
    void DoSomeStuff();
    void DoSomeStuff2();
}
```

This is the implementation:

```
public class CuteInterfaceImplementation<T> : IMyCuteInterface<T>
{
    private readonly T _element;
    public CuteInterfaceImplementation(T element)
    {
        _element = element;
    }

    public void DoSomethingOnlyPossibleIfGenericIsIEnumerable(){}
    public void DoSomeStuff(){}
    public void DoSomeStuff2() { }
}
```

This is a static method to get this more dynamically:

```
public class CuteInterfaceImplementationBase
{
    public static IMyCuteInterface<T> From<T>(T t)
    {
        return new CuteInterfaceImplementation<T>(t);
    }
}
```

and this is the way I want to call it:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var mci = CuteInterfaceImplementationBase.From(args);
}
```

So, C# wants me to add the generic type constraint I added in the first interface to my `CuteInterfaceImplementationBase.From<T>` and my `CuteInterfaceImplementation<T>`-class.

What I want to achieve is: `args` could either be e.g. from type `List<T>` or from type `int` or something else. My target is, if `args` is from type `IEnumerable<T>` I want to add more functions (via the interface with the constraint) to `CuteInterfaceImplementation`-instance.

example:

if args is from type `IEnumerable`, this instance from `CuteInterfaceImplementation` has methods:

- `void DoSomethingOnlyPossibleIfGenericIsIEnumerable();`
- `void DoSomeStuff();`
- `void DoSomeStuff2();`

if args is from type `Foo` or `int` (or any type that doesn't implement `IEnumerable`) I can use methods:

- `void DoSomeStuff();`
- `void DoSomeStuff2();`

means, `DoSomethingOnlyPossibleIfGenericIsIEnumerable` is not available.

But it seems, this is not possible, since I need to add the constraint to my implemented class. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: I think the purpose of `partial` is to split definitions and not for what you want.

Comment: If your class contains DoSomethingOnlyPossibleIfGenericIsIEnumerable - then generic should be IEnumerable, you should not be able to use that class with any other type (and by the way `partial` is irrelevant here, probably you do not understand what partial really does).

Comment: Sorry @Evk, but I know what partial does. And your comment just repeats exactly what I was saying. Yes, it's not possible. My question was, how can I get it to work what I explained in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure that this approach good idea, it violates the "I" in SOLID - [interface 
segregation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle)

> no client should be forced to depend on methods it does not use

You're using `partial` to split up two fundamentally different interfaces, you should have 2 different interface because they are different.

**To answer your question:**
If you're committed to a similar approach on the conditions of `T`, you could split the interfaces, move the "common logic" (which both interfaces use) to a  base class and use the `From<T>` method to conditionally choose which implementation to create.

Something like this:

```
public partial interface IMyCuteInterface_WITHEnumerable<T> : IMyCuteInterface<T> where T : IEnumerable
{
    void DoSomethingOnlyPossibleIfGenericIsIEnumerable();
}

public partial interface IMyCuteInterface<T>
{
    void DoSomeStuff();
    void DoSomeStuff2();
}
```

And then the implementations:

```
public class CuteInterfaceImplementation<T> : CuteInterfaceImplementation_COMMON<T>
{
    public CuteInterfaceImplementation(T element) : base(element)
    {

    }
}

public class CuteInterfaceImplementation_COMMON<T> : IMyCuteInterface<T>
{
    private readonly T _element;
    public CuteInterfaceImplementation_COMMON(T element)
    {
        _element = element;
    }
    public void DoSomeStuff() { }
    public void DoSomeStuff2() { }
}

public class CuteInterfaceImplementation_WITHEnumerable<T> : CuteInterfaceImplementation_COMMON<T>,  IMyCuteInterface_WITHEnumerable<T> where T : IEnumerable
{
    private readonly T _element;
    public CuteInterfaceImplementation_WITHEnumerable(T element) : base(element)
    {
        _element = element;
    }

    public void DoSomethingOnlyPossibleIfGenericIsIEnumerable() { }
}
```

Finally your "static helper", which decides on the class to instantiate:
Unfortunately it's not possible in C# to conditionally instantiate the different classes because one expects `T` to be `IEnumerable` while the other doesn't. You can get around that using `dynamic`

```
public class CuteInterfaceImplementation_HELPER
{
    public static IMyCuteInterface<T> From<T>(T t)
    {
        if (t is IEnumerable)
        {
            dynamic dyn = t;
            return FromEnumerable(dyn);
        }
        else
        {
            return new CuteInterfaceImplementation<T>(t);
        }
    }

    public static IMyCuteInterface<T> FromEnumerable<T>(T t) where T: IEnumerable
    {
        return new CuteInterfaceImplementation_WITHEnumerable<T>(t);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahm yes... you're definitely right. Inheriting from a base-interface is the much better approach. I need to change my code a bit. Thanks!